# Ionic collection-repeat affecting active classes

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have `ng-class` inside of my `ion-list` if the user clicks an item it adds the class `selected`. The problem when using `collection-repeat` is its managing the DOM and changing the `selected` class as I scroll.

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item collection-repeat="contact in contacts | filter:filters" class="contact" ng-click="pickContact($index, $element, this.contact)" ng-model="contactModel" ng-class="{'selected': contact.selectedContact}" toggle-contacts="selected" collection-item-height="150" collection-item-width="'33.3%'">
    <div ng-if="contact.photo.type == 'img'" class="contact-img">
      <img ng-src="{{contact.photo.value}}.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div ng-if="contact.photo.type == 'text'" class="contact-text-placeholder">
      {{contact.photo.value}}
    </div>
    <div class="contact-name">
      {{contact.name}}
    </div>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

How can I avoid this from happening? I want the class to stick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add the class into the data itself.